# Cross-Browser compatibility Tools to simulate Mac Operating system

Tags: manual-testing, cross-browser-testing

Can some one help me finding a suitable simulator to do browser testing on Mac OS. I dont have a Mac with me. I need an online tool or a software which will run smooth with Win 7
I tried with browserstack. Anyone aware of any other tools?

Comment: You say you tried with browserstack.If you're asking this question, apparently browserstack didn't meet your needs. Why? What are you looking for that browserstack couldn't deliver?

Answer (score 1):

Sauce Labs might help.  You should be able to do a trial with them and start a mac/safari emulation just fine.

https://saucelabs.com/